# Getting crashed When navigate the View

Tags: ios

When I Navigate to another View Its Perfectly Navigating ..if Again Back the Originaly View when i again click the button to Navigate i got the crash ...I did't Understand what is the Problem Any One Help To solve this Issues 
    Thanks in Advance

```
TorunamentVC*TETS = [[TorunamentVC alloc]init];
TETS =  (TorunamentVC*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tornmentid"];
TETS.selectDashBoard=selectType;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:TETS animated:YES];
```

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'BYZ-38-t0r-view-8bC-Xf-vdC' and directory 'Main.storyboardc''
>           *** First throw call stack:

Comment: Show the stacktrace and relevant code.

Comment: -(void) tournmentView :(NSString *) selectType{
    
    TorunamentVC*TETS = [[TorunamentVC alloc]init];
    
    TETS =  (TorunamentVC*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tornmentid"];
    TETS.selectDashBoard=selectType;
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:TETS animated:YES];

    
    
    
}

Comment: what is the problem i got this crashed

Comment: Are you sure that this viewcontroller exits in Storyboard?

Comment: it is related to memory issue, clean yiour product and run once

Comment: i did that but its again i got the crashed

Comment: Where did you specified this "tornmentid" in Storyboard?

Comment: in storyboard view controller i assigned the strorybord id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TorunamentVC*TETS = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tornmentid"];
TETS.selectDashBoard=selectType;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:TETS animated:YES];
```

Try this

Comment: hi Dev sorry i got same Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/94D3B1FF-7782-4D0D-9856-16053697D207/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E482648D-FE16-427F-B6D8-B5E13CE42F56/CAPScoringApp.app> (loaded)' with name 'BYZ-38-t0r-view-8bC-Xf-vdC' and directory 'Main.storyboardc'

Comment: i got the same Crash Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/94D3B1FF-7782-4D0D-9856-16053697D207/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E482648D-FE16-427F-B6D8-B5E13CE42F56/CAPScoringApp.app> (loaded)' with name 'BYZ-38-t0r-view-8bC-Xf-vdC' and directory 'Main.storyboardc'

Comment: are you using xib?

Comment: chnage self.storyboard to appropriate storyboard